# How can I convert StreamWriter to a Stream?

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am trying to create a file using FileHelpers and then write that file out using SshNet all in memory.

So far I have the following:

```
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MyObject>();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        engine.WriteStream(sw, MyData);

        SshHelper ssh = new SshHelper("","","");
        ssh.WriteFile("MyPath", sw.BaseStream);
```

However my issue is with the WriteFile method since it requires a Stream parameter and when I run my code I am getting an empty file.

How can I convert my StreamWriter (sw variable) into a Stream parameter?

EDIT:
I've tried both(not at the same time):

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ms.Position = 0;
```

and it still writes a 0 byte file.

I further tested by using FileHelper to write to my local disk to verify that I have data. (Which I do)

Answer (score 2):

your MemoryStream is the stream, the StreamWriter is just writing to it. Try passing ms in, instead of sw.

Comment: Did you rewind the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Before `WriteFile` try setting the Position of your Stream to 0: `ms.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin )`